# Azure B2C Signup or Signin policy - User created or just signedup

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have created a Signin or signup policy. And it works perfectly. I have developed an MVC application that uses the B2C service. When a user login or signup I want to differentiate between the two. If it is a signup I want to add the user to a DB. Is there anyway to know whether the user is redirected from the signin or signup page? Maybe set a different reply url for the signup process? I tried making two different signup/signin policies but couldnt see any specific reply url for each policy. SO same problem.

Claims:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Use - User is new claim]

You can use **User is new** claim to check whether the user is just got signed up or not.

While choosing application claims choose **user is new** claim.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just did a test see image in main post. I am missing something?

Comment: Did you try with existing user or new user?

Comment: A new user. It was through the signup process, the redirect was performed.